# No IPrincipal user information in controller

Tags: c#, authentication, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I have a basic Web API service with a controller that inherits from ApiController. I have read that I should be able to utilise ApiController.User to get the current authenticated users IPrincipal user object. However when I try the following in my constructor, User is empty with no Principal details.

```
[InjectionConstructor]
        public CloudConfigValueController(IDataModelConverter dataModelConverter, IBusinessModelConverter businessModelConverter, ILogger logger)
        {
            var u = User;
            _businessModelConverter = businessModelConverter;
            _dataModelConverter = dataModelConverter;
            _logger = logger;
        }
```

my web.config

```
 <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
```

So why am I getting no identity information in my controller?

Note: out of interest I also tried using an attribute to validate entry to the API Controller, and I found if I dig down deep through many layers of objects, I can find a textual representation of my windows user name - but no IPrincipal. identity.Name below contains the username

```
 public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {

            var wrapper = actionContext.ControllerContext.Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"] as HttpContextWrapper;
            if (wrapper == null)
            {
                Log.InfoFormat("Could not get http context.");
                throw new AuthenticationException("Could not get authorization context");
            }

            var identity = wrapper.Request.LogonUserIdentity;
            if (identity == null)
            {
                Log.InfoFormat("Could not disover identity");
                throw new AuthenticationException("Could not get users identity");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI I actually discovered the problem. If you go to the properties panel of the Web API project (not right click -> Properties) ie just the Properties panel of the csproj file, then there are options there to enable windows authentication and disable anonymous authentication. This worked